# Allowing /sbin/init be SIGSTOPed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, init, sigkill

I know */sbin/init* has special protection against `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` from kernel for obvious reasons.

I have tried telling kernel I want to receive `SIGSTOP` with `ioctl()` (similar to `SIGABRT` and `SIGSEGV` reqs in main()):

```
if (ioctl (0, KDSIGACCEPT, SIGSTOP) == 0) {
    nih_signal_set_handler (SIGSTOP, stop_handler);
```

but `SIGSTOP` doesn't arrive to the `stop_handler()` (from all I know, as `nih_error()` isn't printed in logs).

In `stop_handler()`, I'm resetting the `SIGSTOP` signal handler to `SIG_DFL` (otherwise it would come back to our handler anyways), but this probably leads it being ignored by the kernel again.

**How do I tell kernel I want to have init STOPPED?**

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to take the SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE flag out of its task struct's signal_struct's flags.

By default (i.e. always on unmodified Linux systems) SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE flag is set on init's signal_struct flags.

You could write a kernel module which would poke init's task struct to change it, then you'd be able to send a stop signal to init.

Sending a stop signal to init is a very bad idea though, as zombies would rapidly proliferate if init wasn't reaping them any more.

---

Clarification: This is an in-kernel struct and not part of init's source, nor is it accessible or visible from userspace. To change it you'd need to write some kernel code or patch the kernel. It would be fairly trivial, I imagine, to write a kernel module which just hacks it.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Can I change the task struct from within init's source and recompile it, or does the change require the mentioned kernel module approach? I'm aware of the implications stopping init would cause normally. I need to enable this for a specific case which results a reboot in the end anyways.

Comment: I've clarified this above (It's an in-kernel structure).